# How create a dictionary if I have its values in a list but I don't have its keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I need to create a dictionary. I have its values in a list but I don't have its keys. Its keys are just numbers (1,2,3,4 ...). "Lista" is a list that has the values. The code is the next:

```
nombres= ["Martin", "Milu","Anastasia", "Lupita", "Tomasa", "Pelusa", "Genoveva","Motita"]
tipos= ["canino", "canino", "felino", "felino", "felino", "canino", "bovino", "roedor"]
edades= [12, 9, 10, 8, 9, 2, 14, 1]
pesos= [33, 26, 4, 5, 5, 6, 106.4, 0.34]
numeros=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
lista = []
lista.append(nombres)
lista.append(tipos)
lista.append(edades)
lista.append(pesos)
newlist=lista
diccionario = {}

## Dictionary 

lista = [[lista[col][row] for col in range(4)] for row in range(8)]
```

The dictionary looks like:
{“1” : [Martín, “canino”, 12, 33] , “2” : [“Milú”, “canino”, 9, 26] , “3” : [“Anastasia” ,“felino” , 10, 4] , “4” : [“Lupita” , “felino” , 8 , 5] ... }

Comment: Do you just want a `list` or a `set` of `tuple`s?

Comment: What’s the point of a dict when you don’t have any useful keys? Lists are basically already dicts where the keys are consecutive numbers…

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to get the numbers along with your list. Also you can use `zip` to simplify your code that makes `lista`:

```py
nombres= ["Martin", "Milu","Anastasia", "Lupita", "Tomasa", "Pelusa", "Genoveva","Motita"]
tipos= ["canino", "canino", "felino", "felino", "felino", "canino", "bovino", "roedor"]
edades= [12, 9, 10, 8, 9, 2, 14, 1]
pesos= [33, 26, 4, 5, 5, 6, 106.4, 0.34]

output = dict(enumerate(zip(nombres, tipos, edades, pesos), start=1))
print(output)

# {1: ('Martin', 'canino', 12, 33), 2: ('Milu', 'canino', 9, 26),
#  3: ('Anastasia', 'felino', 10, 4), 4: ('Lupita', 'felino', 8, 5),
#  5: ('Tomasa', 'felino', 9, 5), 6: ('Pelusa', 'canino', 2, 6),
#  7: ('Genoveva', 'bovino', 14, 106.4), 8: ('Motita', 'roedor', 1, 0.34)}
```

If you do want to use `numeros` as your keys, you can instead use nested `zip`:

```py
output = dict(zip(numeros, zip(nombres, tipos, edades, pesos)))
# {'1': ('Martin', 'canino', 12, 33), ...}
```

---

However, usually people might prefer a data structure like the following:

```py
keys = ["nombre", "tipo", "edad", "peso"]
output = [dict(zip(keys, info)) for info in zip(nombres, tipos, edades, pesos)]
print(output) # [{'nombre': 'Martin', 'tipo': 'canino', 'edad': 12, 'peso': 33}, ...]

print(output[0]['edad']) # 12
```

Or alternatively, assuming the names are unique:

```py
output = {nombre: {'tipo': tipo, 'edad': edad, 'peso': peso}
            for nombre, tipo, edad, peso in zip(nombres, tipos, edades, pesos)}
print(output) # {'Martin': {'tipo': 'canino', 'edad': 12, 'peso': 33}, ...}
print(output['Tomasa']['peso']) # 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the function "[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)" will help you.
Something like this:

```
nombres= ["Martin", "Milu", "Anastasia", "Lupita", "Tomasa", "Pelusa", "Genoveva", "Motita"]

result = {key: value for key, value in enumerate(nombres, start=1)}
```